# How can I disable a checkbox once it has been checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a checkbox. First, I checked, then I want to change the check, and it's possible now.

However, I want to disable this. No one will be allowed to change that checkbox value once selected.

For this what can I do in my code:

**view**

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Language Known</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="lang_known"/> Hindi
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="lang_known" value="2" /> French
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by Jquery like this :

```
<input class="something" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

In Jquery

```
   //On click
   $('.something').on('click', function() {
        //disable if checked
        $(this).prop("disabled", this.checked );
    });
```

[Reference Prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc-1)

> [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8dhtk73h/)